# Does Google Cloud App Engine Firewall have some API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've been searching about if Google App Engine (GAE from  now on) has some kind of DDOs protection. Apparently it had but it's been replaced with GAE Firewall which allows you to choose which IPs to allow to access your App.

This firewall raises 2 questions on me:

1. If someone tries to launch a DDOs attack on my App. Will they success or will they fail? I want to believe that Google will stop it automatically (or try at least) but I don't really know if it does.
2. Is there some kind of API for pogramming languages like Java to modify the allowed IPs in the Firewall so that I can programatically forbid IPs that I feel are dangerous? I haven't been able to find anything for this and it'd be really great.

Thanks!

Comment: If you google "google app engine firewall api", the top response describes an API.

Comment: can you link it? I don't see any API for Java, they just say the to do stuff from the console in google cloud

Answer (score 1):

You can manage your firewall rule programmatically using [AppEngine Admin APIs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.firewall.ingressRules) which have a [Java client available here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-appengine/v1) (however I couldn't find the call for updating firewall rules).

Comment: weird, they have a Firewall model but not anything to use it...

Comment: If that's the case you can use the rest api to achieve that :) also check the latest version on mvn central, you never know !

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found it. Here's a list of libraries for various programming languages: https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries?hl=es

And what seems to be what I'm looking for is the `FirewallClient` which has method  `insertFirewall(InsertFirewallHttpRequest request)`: https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the security of your app my recommendation is to use the [Identity-aware-proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart). This should offer full protection to your app, not only for DDoS attacks.

Comment: this won't do what I need. Anyone will still be able to DDoS me still. I need to block any http request to my server

Comment: Not really. With IAP enabled only the users that you allow to access would access your application from the first instance. Even if anyone tries to attack your app, as the proxy acts like a first, load-balancing wall between the user and the application, the attack won't even reach your backend

Comment: but I need to allow any user with google, fb or twitter to login, not only a set of google users

Comment: I understand. This is some other discussion then. I think you found the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Cloud Armor it’s the best solution :

https://cloud.google.com/armor